# Cocoa How to know if a file was closed

Tags: macos, file, cocoa, events

How to detect a file is closed? I tried FSEvent, but noting happened. I used FSEventStreamCreate to create the event. How can I know if the file was closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a file was closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181005/how-to-detect-if-a-file-was-closed)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It almost solved my problem. But when I open a txt file, It always notice me the file is closed. How to fix it?